# boost logging with filters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I am new to [boost-log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/) and tried to make the [trivial logging with filters](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/trivial_filtering.html) example work with boost-log 1.1. The code looks like this:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/filters.hpp>

void init()
{
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
     filters::attr< logging::trivial::severity_level >("Severity") >= logging::trivial::info
     );
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
}
```

Compiling this with clang results the following error messages:

```
/Users/admin/Documents/cmake tests/boost-log/main.cpp:7:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'logging'
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    ^
/Users/admin/Documents/cmake tests/boost-log/main.cpp:9:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'filters'; did you mean 'boost::log_mt_posix::filters'?
         filters::attr< logging::trivial::severity_level >("Severity") >= logging::trivial::info
         ^~~~~~~
         boost::log_mt_posix::filters
/usr/local/include/boost/log/filters/has_attr.hpp:32:11: note: 'boost::log_mt_posix::filters' declared here
namespace filters {
          ^
/Users/admin/Documents/cmake tests/boost-log/main.cpp:9:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'logging'
         filters::attr< logging::trivial::severity_level >("Severity") >= logging::trivial::info
```

It looks like the example is based on an older version of boost-log and some names have changed. Can the example be easily fixed? An updated tutorial however does not seem to be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example in the docs just seems to be missing the following lines after the includes:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace filters = boost::log::filters;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's the case for most of the documentation which makes it really hard for a beginner to find all the necessary includes and namespaces :(